# How do you comment out code snippets within a seam pdf file

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, seam, itext

How do you comment out pieces of code within a seam PDF generation file. XML style comments don't seem to work and the commented out code appears as it is in the pdf file.

```
            <p:font name="times-roman" size="12" style="bold normal">
                <p:text value="Full Name."/>
            </p:font>

            <p:font name="times-roman" size="9" style="normal">
                <p:text value=" #{abc.firstName}  "/>
            </p:font>
```

Comment: Which library are you using to generate pdf files?

Comment: jboss seam pdf module using itext

Answer (score 1):

According to [Adobe PDF Reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html):

> Any occurrence of the percent sign
> character (%) outside a string or
> stream introduces a comment. The
> comment consists of all characters
> between the percent sign and the end
> of the line, including regular,
> delimiter, space, and tab characters.
> PDF ignores comments, treating them as
> if they were single white-space
> characters. That is, a comment
> separates the token preceding it from
> the one following it; thus, the PDF
> fragment
>
> abc% comment { /% ) blah blah blah
>
> 123
>
> is syntactically equivalent
> to just the tokens abc and 123.

I have not used JBoss Seam myself, but I guess you could try combining the two comment styles (xml and PDF) in your xml input file so that your comments are not visible in the resulting pdf file.

Comment: The PDF file structure uses byte offsets internally so manually inserting comments into a PDF will most likely mess up the structure of the document. Some PDF readers will try to compensate for this type of error but you're very likely to corrupt the document.

Comment: @Marnix I think the question is about generating a PDF file using an xml configuration as input. If this is the case, I do not see how inserting pdf comments in the input file will corrupt the output file.

Comment: Inserting comments during generation would not be a problem, however your answer could be easily misinterpreted as suggesting that it's perfectly ok to insert comments into a PDF document.

Comment: @Marnix I have modified my answer a little bit to reflect your remark. Thanks for your comment.